# Retrieve JSON from DB

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is the JSON Object

```
var stockused = { "fuel": {  "1": "522",  "2": "311" }, "spares": {  "1": "6" }}
```

I submit it to the DB after serializing it ( using JQuery `.serialize()`) .
The serialized form looks like this :

```
%7B+%22fuel%22%3A+%7B++%221%22%3A+%22522%22%2C++%222%22%3A+%22311%22+%7D%2C+%22spares%22%3A+%7B++%221%22%3A+%226%22+%7D%7D
```

When i try to retrieve the same field from DB on to a Page i get something like this :

```
{ \"fuel\": { \"1\": \"522\", \"2\": \"311\" }, \"spares\": { \"1\": \"6\" }}
```

As i understand that `.serialize()` performs URL encoding, i have performed URL decoding using `urldecode` function in `PHP` to obtain the above result.

How can i have this output as a pure JSON object?

Comment: Its a simple codeigniter script, just taking the input from post and putting it an array and sending it to the DB using Active Record Class Insert Method. No PHP operations are performed on the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unescape the string first:

```
$unescaped_data = str_replace('\"','"',$data);
```

The use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it. One liner:

```
$json_obj = json_decode(str_replace('\"','"',$data));
```

OR
you can also use [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes)

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($data), 1);
```

**Test:**

```
$str = "{ \"fuel\": { \"1\": \"522\", \"2\": \"311\" }, \"spares\": { \"1\": \"6\" }}";
$json_obj = json_decode(stripslashes($str));
$json_array = json_decode(stripslashes($str), 1);
print_r($json_obj);
print "<br />";
print_r($json_array);
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object ( [fuel] => stdClass Object ( [1] => 522 [2] => 311 ) [spares] => stdClass Object ( [1] => 6 ) ) 

Array ( [fuel] => Array ( [1] => 522 [2] => 311 ) [spares] => Array ( [1] => 6 ) )
```

Comment: I had tried the First Answer, it yields a string, But `json_decode` doesnt make that string a `JSON` object

On trying 3rd answer I get this Error : `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: try it with a 1 as the second argument to json_decode